# Rest parameter with specific types

Tags: typescript

I can declare a rest parameter like

```
function f(...args: (number | string)[]) { }
```

But if I want to specify types of array elements

```
function g(...args: [number, string]) { }
```

I'm getting an error

> A rest parameter must be of an array type.

How can I fix it?

Comment: [Related issue.](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5453)

Comment: Maybe wait for [TypeScript 3.0](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Roadmap#30-july-2018) to get [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/24897)?

Comment: `[number, string]` is not an array type, it's a [tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple) - that is, array with first element that must be `number`, second must be `string`, and the rest can be either `number` or `string`. I don't see why you'd want to use such a type for rest parameters - just declare the first two elements as normal parameters, and use the first form in your question for the rest.

Comment: Or indeed wait until [this PR](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/24897) and the following promised commits implementing open-ended tuple types are merged and next version is released

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting form Typescript 3 this syntax is supported.

```
function g(...args: [number, string]) { }
```